# Using ScriptingBridge and Python, what properties can I get from the track currently playing?

Tags: python, itunes, scripting-bridge

I'm using [this](http://www.unessa.net/en/hoyci/2011/07/itunes-from-python/) example as a basis and would love to retrieve a bit more information about the current track. For instance, what the current time of the track is (where the "playhead" is) and what the total track length is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get into using Python and AppleEvent scripting, I would strongly urge you to use [`py-appscript`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/) rather than Scripting Bridge.  appscript is robust and well-maintained by its independent developer, whereas Scripting Bridge does not seem to be high on the radar anymore at Apple.  `py-appscript` is also supported on both Python 2 and Python 3.

You can the ASDictionary tool provided by `appscript` to explore the scripting dictionaries provided by scriptable applications.  Or you can view the dictionary in Apple's `AppleScript Editor.app` (previously known as `Script Editor`) and manually translate the syntax.  In this case, after installing `py-appscript` in one of your Python instances, it is pretty easy.  In the scripting dictionary definition for iTunes, there are various properties listed for the `application` object.  One listed is:

**player position** (integer) : the player’s position within the currently playing track in seconds.

Another is:

**player state** (stopped/‌playing/‌paused/‌fast forwarding/‌rewinding, r/o) : is iTunes stopped, paused, or playing?

To make valid Python names, `py-appscript` automatically replaces any space characters with an underscore character:

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> it = app('iTunes')   # the "application" object
>>> it.player_state()    # access properties of the "application" object
k.playing
>>> it.player_position() #   (calling the property "( )" implies a "get" action)
1958
>>> it.player_position()
1961
>>> it.current_track.artist()
u'Bavarian Radio Symphony Orchestra'
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the appscript website suggests using Scripting Bridge (or other alternatives) instead of appscript. http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html

Answer (score 1):

The *right* way to get information about the scripting properties of an application is to open its dictionary via AppleScript Editor.  This presents everything in an appropriate context, along with documentation.

However, sometimes we don't care about the *right* way to do things, we just want a *Python* way, hmm?  And, in Python (via PyObjC) you can inspect lots of classes at runtime with tools like `.__dict__`and `dir`.  So, you can compare the attributes of an iTunes application object to the vanilla `SBApplication` object, or the attributes of any random scripting thing to a vanilla `SBObject`, and this is what you get:

```
>>> from ScriptingBridge import SBObject, SBApplication
>>> iTunes = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")
>>> (list(set(dir(iTunes)) - set(dir(SBApplication))))
['fullScreen', 'selection', 'mute', 'visuals', 'setSoundVolume_',
# ...
'setVisualSize_', 'currentStreamURL', 'setFixedIndexing_']
>>> (list(set(dir(iTunes.currentTrack())) - set(dir(SBObject))))
['rating', 'databaseID', 'setUnplayed_', 'lyrics', 'show', 'releaseDate',
# ...
'setSkippedCount_', 'skippedCount', 'setSeasonNumber_', 'sampleRate']
```

As it happens, the "player head" is an attribute of the application (you can only play one song at a time) not the current track (which is actually the same "track" object you'd get even if it weren't the one that was playing, just representing the metadata, not the play-state).  Both it and the track's "duration" attribute are in seconds, so you can compute (for example) the percentage through the song like so:

```
>>> "{0:0.0f}%".format((iTunes.playerPosition() / iTunes.currentTrack().duration()) * 100)
```